# Regex: Index and Length returned as 0 with Match.Success = true

Tags: c#, regex

I was going through a tutorial on regex and came across this code

```
  string pattern = "a*";
  string subject = "za";
  Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
  var match = reg.Match(subject);
  if(match.Success)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Index: {0} Length: {1}", match.Index, match.Length);
    }
```

The output of this code is

```
Index: 0 Length: 0
```

The author of the tutorial says that this was expected as an empty match has happened.

Can someone explain this please

Comment: I marked it as a dupe of a JS related post because the explanation is valid for this .NET case.

Comment: a* -> match only string with 0 or more a

Comment: Yes, `a*` can match an empty string and it finds it right before `z`. Since `reg.Match` only looks for the first match here, no other locations are tested.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew